# Finding $A^TA = B^TB + I$ where $B$ is known and $I$ is identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Does it exist any explicit formula for $A$, if $B$ is known and I is identity? But without using decomposition of $B^TB$, since numeric error is too large for using $B^TB = U\Lambda U^T$ or without using $B^TB + I = U\Lambda U^T$ and take $A = \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} U^T$.

Comment: $A$ is not uniquely determined by this equation, take $B=0$. Then $A$ is just an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Since $B^TB+I$ is positive definite, you can do [Cholesky factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) (it is much cheaper than $U\Lambda U^T$): $B^TB+I=L^TL$. Then all (square) solutions are $A=QL$ where $Q$ is any orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can note that $B^TB + I = B^TB + I^TI$. Thus, we can take $A = (B \quad I)$. It can be easily verified that $A^TA = B^TB + I^TI$. This is the cheapest solution, since we don't need to do any additional computation.

Comment: in your question, you implicitly assume that $A$ is a square matrix (when you write "$A = \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} U^T$"). In your hilarious answer, you choose a non-square solution matrix! The last but not the least, you assign yourself the green chevron. My friend, you should be doing politics.  (-1)

Comment: Actually, it was not implicitly assumed, it was just proposal of one solution. My aim was not to find square matrix $A$, but any matrix $A$ for which that equality holds. Fiirstly, I used Cholesky Factorization proposed in comments, then I find that I can use this form of $A$, so I think this is the best way, in which $A$ can be found, that the reason I shared it here, so this was nothing about self-promotion @loup blanc.